# Access my controller gives object not found error in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Hi i am having issue with accessing mycontroller in laravel 4. I have created my controller HiController with php artisan and mentioned in the Routes file as below:

Route::get('hi', 'HiController');

When i tried to open it in browser http://localhost/larstart/public/hi it is giving below error

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

Xampp 1.8.1 OS Windows 7 Home Basic

I have removed my .htaccess from my public folder to access the default page.
I have google and tried different solutions but i am not able to solve the issue

Comment: Route should have a method that you want to call. Like this `Route::get('hi', 'HiController@get');`

Comment: @Dhiraj i have called method as you said Route::get('hi', 'HiController@index'); same error is displaying in browser. I have only index() in my controller. This is my controller <?php

class HiController extends \BaseController {

 public function index(){
 
  return View::make('hello');
  //echo 'hi';
 
 }
 
}

Comment: @Dhiraj i have added my .htaccess to public folder and changed <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs"> AllowOverride FileInfo to
 AllowOverride All in d://xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf then working fine. But if i change in routes file as Route::get('hi', 'HiController'); it is giving  Undefined offset: 1

Comment: You have to give `@index` or some method for sure. You dont need a `.htaccess`

Comment: @dhiraj Thank you very much for sparing your time. But anyhow it works. Without the method it wont load the index page ? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: If you want the route to without a method then it should be `Route::resource('hi','HiController')` then the default method would be `index` in the controller otherwise if you are specifying like `Route::get` then you should specify the method like `HiController@index`

Comment: Please check, if the mod_rewrite module is enabled in your XAMPP server or not. That is required for the RESTFUL route.

Comment: @dhiraj i have my index() function in my controller as public function index() and in my route i am calling as Route::get('hi', 'HiController'); it is giving error "
ErrorException

Undefined offset: 1
"

Comment: as i said earlier, if you do not want to give an method in your route you should use the word `resource` like this  `Route::resource('hi','HiController')` and you should have index method in your controller. If you use `Route::get()` you will have to provide a method like this `Route::get('hi', 'HiController@index');`

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla: i am very thankful to you for getting me the information and it solves my problem thanks once again for your help!